# Adding back button to a view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created 3 `UIViewControllers` for my 3 `UIToolBar` items but i am not able to create a button on each controller which takes me back to the home page or main view controller. Kindly help me as i am new to objective c.

Here is my  code....

**"ViewController.h"**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ContactInfoViewController.h"
#import "DateViewController.h"
#import "MessageViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 417, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
UIBarButtonItem *contact = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contact" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(ContactButton)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexiableItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *date = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(DateButton)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexiableItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *message = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(MessageButton)];
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:contact,flexiableItem1,date,flexiableItem,message, nil];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
[items release];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
}
-(void)ContactButton
{
ContactInfoViewController *secondViewcont = [[ContactInfoViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewcont];
[self presentViewController:navigCont animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(void)DateButton
{
DateViewController *secondViewcont = [[DateViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewcont];
[self presentViewController:navigCont animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(void)MessageButton
{
MessageViewController *secondViewcont = [[MessageViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigCont = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:secondViewcont];
[self presentViewController:navigCont animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add custom button to your second view controller

In `viewDidLoad` you can do like this

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)]autorelease];


- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```